# Android Studio emulator opens but the sceen is black

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, hyper-v

I'm have a lot of trouble trying to make android studio emulator to work. It opens but the screen is black doesn;t matter how much time i wait.

I'm running leatest android studio.
[image]

My Processor have AMD-Virtualization Enabled. Its AMD Phenom II X4 955.
My Grahics card is AMD Radeon HD 5850.

At first i have been setting it up like in this tutorial for react native for windows -> Android:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

But when ever i was trying just to run Android AVD of Nexus 5X, Nexus 5 or Pixel 2 with Android Pie, Q with API LVL 29 or similar all i could encounter is black screen.
I have checked OpenGL my grahpics card is useing. Right now its 4.5.

I have tried running it with and without Hyper-V and the rest of the stuff that is highlighted below this image:
[image]

I was also trying switching on and off this setting:
[image]

**While doing Hyper-V stuff i also were disableing Hyper-V via command prompt and power shell.**

While doing all this stuff i was restarting my system and android studio mutlply times.
I had installed Java Se openjdk8.0 and openjdk17.0 during tests. And android studio environment were set up like in the react native tutorial above as well as in youtube tutorial how to install android studio later.

I have no idea what to do next. I can;t get it to run. Also i can;t see why becouse what ever requiremnts i;m checking and what ever fix i see in the internet it just won;t work.

**P.S. I was also recreating avd's, wipeing thier data, and trying the power button after it opens. I was also playing around with the amount of Ram assigened, but usually i left it at 1,5 GB of Ram, and used emulated preformace grahpic for both software, hardware and auto.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the memory that use your emulate phone, sometimes it load slow by this

Comment: Do u mean the amount of Ram memeory assigned to the Avd's ? If thats it i was running most of the times on 1,5 GB, tried a few time 3Gb but it changed nothing. But might as well check again. If thats what u ment ?

Comment: Yes, I mean RAM memory. Sometimes, in my desktop machine starts so slow.

Comment: If that is what u ment i have just tried Nexus 4 avd with Android Q with 4096 MB of Ram and nothing.

Comment: Have you been tried change the emulated performance, like this: https://www.jc-tech.info/2017/07/12/android-emulator-hanging-with-black-screen/#:~:text=If%20the%20Android%20Studio%20emulator%20hangs%20with%20a,the%20LogCat%20messages%20and%20try%20switching%20graphics%20mode. ?

Comment: I have tried it. But i double checked it right now again. Nexus 4 - Android Q - 29 API LVL. emulated perfomrance on auto, hardware and software doesn;t seem to change anything. I gave each option a few minutes just in case.